# ROAuth handshake

Tags: r, twitter, oauth, handshake, rcurl

I have been trying to authenticate through ROAuth using the following script:

```
    library("ROAuth")
    library("RCurl")

requestURL <- "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token"
accessURL = "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token"
authURL = "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize"


cKey<- "Key"
cSecret<- "Secret"


Cred <- OAuthFactory$new(consumerKey=cKey,
            consumerSecret=cSecret,
            requestURL=requestURL,
            accessURL=accessURL,
            authURL=authURL)

Cred$handshake(cainfo = system.file("CurlSSL", "cacert.pem", package = "RCurl"))
```

Every time I enter in this code, I get the error:

```
Error in Cred$handshake(cainfo = system.file("CurlSSL", "cacert.pem",  : Invalid response from site, please check your consumerKey and consumerSecret and try again.
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong. I have made sure every necessary package is up to date by re-installing ROauth and RCurl and checking their version information (ROAuth 0.9.1 and  RCurl_1.91-1.1(?) ). After installation, I restarted R (as a possible solution suggested by another post). I copy-pasted and double-checked the consumer key and consumer secret, and I am sure they are correct. Does anyone have any other ideas?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the handshake method in ROauth was broken but was since fixed. The error message you posted (the same one I'm getting right now) is the same as the one referenced in the following link:

http://lists.hexdump.org/pipermail/twitter-users-hexdump.org/2012-February/000059.html

I'm guessing there's still an issue so will see if I can find anything else out...

Answer (score 0):

I can't help with RCurl/ROAuth — but you could try the package ‛httr‛ https://github.com/hadley/httr/ . It comes with a demo how to access Twitter.